# Is there a default port that is requested by web browsers?

Tags: port, localhost

If I request `http://localhost` do browsers try a specific port?

Perhaps people set the default port server side?  Or must ports be specified (eg. `http://localhost:1234`)?

I'm trying to make it as simple as I can for a client to connect to a locally hosted "remote controller" website.

Comment: http by default is port 80 while https defaults to 443. If you are hosting on a different port the client must specify which port.

Comment: strange.  I though port numbers were 4 digits long.  If setting up a port, would it be 0080.  My current program crashes if given a less than four digit number... but perhaps that's an issue elsewhere.

Comment: got it, sudo is required for ports < 1024

Comment: setting up the port where? and BTW the port numbers are from 0 to 65535 [see here for list of common port usage](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### If I request http://localhost do browsers try a specific port?

There are three [well known ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) commonly used by web servers:

- Port 80: for [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol).
- Port 8080 is often used as an alternative to port 80, for applications such as [Apache Tomcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) and [Atlassian JIRA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jira_(software)).
- Port 443: for [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS).

You can, of course configure your local web server to use whatever ports you like.

---

#### Further Reading

- [Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml)

Comment: Thank you.  I've also just found that certain permissions (sudo) are required for ports < 1024.

Comment: @SephReed On Unix systems, yes.

Comment: I wasn't until I tried port 80 as per directed by this answer.  It's not really in total relation to this question, but it still seems useful enough to share.

Comment: This link, posted above, might be a nice thing to add to the answer, just to wrap everything up:   https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml

Answer (score 5):

- Default HTTP Port: **80**
- Default HTTPS Port: **443**

Following is some of the recommended **localhost** ports for local developments.

- Recommended `Express.js`(or `LoopBack` ) Dev Port: **3000**, **8000**, **8080** (by `npm start`)
- Default `Angular` Webpack Dev Port: **4200** (by `ng serve`)
- Default `Ionic` Webpack Dev Port: **8100**, **8200** (by `ionic serve` or `ionic lab`)

...

> List of Well-Known Ports Port numbers range from 0 to 65535, but only
>   port numbers 0 to 1023 are reserved for privileged services and
>   designated as well-known ports. The following list of well-known port
>   numbers specifies the port used by the server process as its contact
>   port.
>
> Well-known ports range from 0 through
>   1023. Registered ports are 1024 to 49151. Dynamic ports (also called private ports) are 49152 to 65535.

https://www.webopedia.com/quick_ref/portnumbers.asp

Comment: The default port in Laravel is also 80. (with php artisan serve)